# Как установить pip и easy_install python(вторая ветка) под windows ?

Tags: python, windows

Как установить `pip python` (вторая ветка) под `windows`?
Какие шаги надо предпринять?

Answer (score 2):

[Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) неплохо описан нужный вам процесс